# How to calculate precision of Pound-Drever-Hall technique?

Tags: laser, frequency, stability, noise, precession

When I read the fifth section (Noise and fundamental limits: how well can you do?) of [Eric's article](http://elmer.tapir.caltech.edu/ph237/week13/BlackAJP01.pdf), I have question.
In this section(page 85 and 86), Eric discussed the shot noise, and gave the spectral density of the shot noise as the form of $S_e$, $S_f$ and $S_L$. Then he gave two examples. But I have some trouble to understand the two equation.
$S_f=(1.2\times10^{-5}\frac {Hz}{\sqrt Hz})\frac {10^4}{F}\frac {20 cm}{L}\sqrt{\frac {1064nm}{\lambda}\frac {500mW}{P_c}}$
$S_L=(8.1\times10^{-21}\frac {m}{\sqrt Hz})\frac {10^4}{F}\sqrt{\frac {\lambda}{1064nm}\frac {500mW}{P_c}}$
Does the first expression mean that $10^4$ is equal to $F$, $20cm$ is equal to $L$, $1064nm$ is equal to $\lambda$, $500mW$ is equal to $P_c$, and the value in the blank $1.2\times10^{-5}\frac {Hz}{\sqrt Hz}$ is equal to $\frac {\sqrt {hc^3}}{8}$? **But neither the value ($1.2\times10^{-5}$) nor the unit ($\frac {Hz}{\sqrt Hz}$) accord to the expression ($\frac {\sqrt {hc^3}}{8}$). Why?** And the second expression is the same.
When I read other articles about frequency stabilization, they usually mention that the system can achieve laser's linewidth less than a certain frequency value, for example $10Hz$. I wonder **how to predict this value when I design the system.** Or I can only get the linewidth after I have tested the circuit?